# SQL to return all the rows of a table as a single string

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL, and I have a table with 3 records:

```
id, name
1, bill
2, joe
3, sam
```

I'm looking for a single SQL statement that will return all the ids as a CSV string:

```
'1,2,3'
```

This gives me multiple records:

```
select id from tablename
```

I'm thinking that I need to use version of the concat function in MySQL, but it's not clear what.

```
select concat(id) from tablename
```

But this returns the same as the original (multiple records). Is there an easy way to "collapse" the records to a single row?

Please note that I just need a single string of the "id" column values, not any other columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) 
FROM tablename;
```

or:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id) 
FROM tablename;
```